# Gunicorn shared memory between multiprocessing processes and workers

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gunicorn

I have an python application that uses a dictionary as a shared memory between multiple processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
manager = Manager()
shared_dict = manager.dict()
```

REST API is implemented using Flask. While using pywsgi or simply Flask.run to initialise the Flask server everything was working fine.
I decided to throw in the mix gunicorn. Now, when I access this shared dict from any of the workers (even when only one is running) I get the error:

> message = connection.recv_bytes(256)         # reject large message
>   IOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable

I have been looking into mmap, multiprocessing Listener and Client and they all looked like a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the specific error, but I think the most probable cause is that when you add the web server, processes are initialized on demand, so the `manager_dict` is lost within calls. If the dict is not big enough and you can pay the serialization/de-serialization penalty, using [redis](http://redis.io/) in-memory data structure store with the [py-redis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis) library is rather straightforward.